# How to declare If Statement in mysql triggers

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to create a trigger in phpmyadmin. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this query, it keeps telling me MySQL error #1064, SQL Syntax[image]

Comment: *telling me MySQL error #1064, SQL Syntax* Provide **complete and unchanged** error message.

Comment: Do not linebreak datetime literal.

Comment: It's not fixing the issue

Comment: Also `count` is reserved word/keyword, so the column/variable name must be enclosed with backticks.

Comment: I tried to change the variable 'count' to 'updatedcount', and the error still persists.

Comment: **WHAT** error ??? Where is **complete** error message ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no `BEGIN` at the start of the trigger body, to match the `end` on the last line.